# Getting a bad request bad request 400 when creating user(Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, localhost

I am developing a web app and I'm using Firebase for that. Since I do not have a domain name yet, I'm trying to use my localhost. I can see localhost in `OAuth redirect domains`. Also the initializing part is working fine.

But when I create a user using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword` it shows `[HTTP/2.0 400 Bad Request 447ms]` when posting to `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword`.

I'm new to web app development and Firebase web as well. Somebody please help me to do this using my localhost.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the entire function you use to create users? signInWithEmailAndPassword wouldn't you use to create users, but to sign in users already registrered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Updated on Mar 29th, 2024**

Please note the following two points when you use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create a new account:

1. Check if you get `auth/weak-password` error code when using a weak password (less than 6 chars)
2. Check if you try to use a registered email (Hozayfa and Aakash mentioned)

This password policy performs on updating an existing account's password as well.

See also:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException

Comment: Thank you for the week password hint, I was writing the code well and was going crazy why it return error 400, it was that I typed always a 4 characters password. Thank you again.

Comment: I was trying to use a registered email.

Comment: My two mistakes were that I was using a weak password and secondly I was using a registered email, it will give you an error in console, check carefully.